# how i can precise this python code into few lines?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-analysis

I want to precise this code where I am finding **mean** which is updating data frame. How I can find patterns and take this code in few lines.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Dataset2.csv')
df = df.to_numpy()

for i in range (0,len(df)):

     mean_1 = df[i,1:5].sum() / 4
     mean_2 = (df[i,0:1].sum() + df[i,2:5].sum()) / 4 
     mean_3 = (df[i,0:2].sum() + df[i,3:5].sum()) / 4 
     mean_4 = (df[i,0:3].sum() + df[i,4:5].sum()) / 4
     mean_5 = df[i,0:4].sum() / 4
    
   
     df[i,0] = df[i,0] - mean_1
     df[i,1] = df[i,1] - mean_2
     df[i,2] = df[i,2] - mean_3
     df[i,3] = df[i,3] - mean_4
     df[i,4] = df[i,4] - mean_5
```

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of what you are trying to do is

*given a dataframe df, create a new dataframe where the value of the element in row i, column j, is given by the mean of all values in row i - except the one in column j*

If this is correct then the following will be much quicker.  It assumes the dataframe only consists of columns necessary for this calculation.  If there are extra columns you will need to adjust the solution with indexing

```
means = (df.sum(axis=1).reshape((len(df),1)) - df)/4
```

`means` will be a numpy array so wrap it up in a pandas Dataframe if that's what you need

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_frame',

row_sums is numpy array not dataframe

Comment: @hassan this answer has been updated

Comment: ' mean_1 = df[i,1:5].sum() / 4
     mean_2 = (df[i,0:1].sum() + df[i,2:5].sum()) / 4 
     mean_3 = (df[i,0:2].sum() + df[i,3:5].sum()) / 4 
     mean_4 = (df[i,0:3].sum() + df[i,4:5].sum()) / 4
     mean_5 = df[i,0:4].sum() / 4
    
   
     df[i,0] = df[i,0] - mean_1
     df[i,1] = df[i,1] - mean_2
     df[i,2] = df[i,2] - mean_3
     df[i,3] = df[i,3] - mean_4
     df[i,4] = df[i,4] - mean_5 '



, **only want to precise this bro**

Comment: I have no idea what that means

Comment: the code part after for loop above in my question ,  **as far your solution gives attribute error of values**

Comment: Use the updated solution

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Comment: You can't get this error if `df` is a numpy array, which you convert it to on your 4th line....

Comment: yup got it thanks for sharing